# htaccess SEO url Include styles failed.. How to fix this?

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am working on my website, and have made "SEO url's" using the .htaccess file. 
So taht website.eu/contact equals website.eu/index.php?file=contact. and website.eu/case/somthing equalc website.eu/index.php?file=case&ID=somthing. Now my problem is that if the addres is website.eu/contact/ the styles wont get loaded.

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteOptions inherit

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews

RewriteBase /habberdesign

## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}s([^.]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?file=$2.php&ID=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?file=$2.php&ID=$3

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?file=404.php

RewriteRule ^countdown /countdown
```

Styles:

```
<link href="Styles/contact.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Optionally** You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

**Update:** Also remember that `RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Hence your rules should be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews

RewriteBase /habberdesign

## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}s([^.]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?file=$2.php&ID=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?file=$2.php&ID=$3 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?file=404.php

RewriteRule ^countdown /countdown [L]
```